# bindingNavigator _Validating event not returning control to the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to follow the MSDN example code for the `Control.Validating Event` and to apply it to a `bindingNavigator` item instead of the `textbox` as in the example.

The code provided for the textbox validation event is shown below.

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, 
                System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   string errorMsg;
   if(!ValidEmailAddress(textBox1.Text, out errorMsg))
   {
      // Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
      e.Cancel = true;
      textBox1.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length);
      // Set the ErrorProvider error with the text to display. 
      this.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, errorMsg);
   }
}
```

I too intend on validating texboxes however I have several and have already written the validation methods for them which handle the error messages. I would like these methods to be tested when the user selects an item (Arrow buttons / Save button / Add button) on the `bindingNavidator`.

I therefore have the code below to attempt this,

```
private void myBindingNavigator_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

  if (!IsPostCodeValid())
  {
    PostCodeTextBox.Focus();
    e.Cancel = true;   
  }

}
```

I have the `ItemClicked` event for the bindingNavigator set to `bindingNavigator.Focus()` with the hope of initiating the Validating event. (`myBindingNavigator.CausesValidation = true;` has been declared on formLoad). However I feel this is where an infinite loop of focusing the Navigation bar follows? I have stepped through and no code is executed once it has locked on to the Navigation bar it simply won't let the user interact with the rest of the form to change and correct the error after the navigation bar has been locked onto.

I can provide any extra information required and test any suggestions to discover what is going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with `BindingNavigator` and you have put your controls in details mode on the form, to ensure save only valid data, you should write validation rules for your controls and also you should handle your binding navigator items yourself.

This way you even don't need to set [`AutoValidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51d5b3a8(v=vs.110).aspx) Property of your form to annoying `EnablePreventFocusChange` and you can set it to be the friendly [`EnableAllowFocusChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autovalidate(v=vs.110).aspx) and because you can't navigate or save anything when there is validation errors, then you can be sure only valid data will save in database.

To do so, follow these steps:

**Step 1**

Handle `Validating` event of child controls and set `e.cancel = true` when the value is not valid.

```
private void nameTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Put validation logic here
    if (this.nameTextBox.Text.Length < 10)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.nameTextBox, "Some Error");
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(this.nameTextBox, "");
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

Go to `BindingNavigator` properties, and set `MoveFirstItem`, `MovePreviousItem`, `MoveNextItem`, `MoveLastItem`, `AddNewItem`, `DeleteItem` properties To `(none)`. Also from designer click on the text box that shows record number, it is `bindingNavigatorPositionItem`, and then set its `ReadOnly` property to `true`.

**Step 3**

For all buttons, including navigation buttons, add button, delete button, save button and other custom buttons, handle `Click` event and call [`ValidateChildren`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the container of your text boxes and check if `ValidateChildren()` doesn't return true, exit the method, else do the task that the method should do, for example:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.ValidateChildren())
        return;

    //Put the logic for this button here
    //MoveFirstItem: `this.myBindingSource.MoveFirst();`
    //MovePreviousItem: `this.myBindingSource.MovePrevious();`
    //MoveNextItem: `this.myBindingSource.MoveNext();`
    //MoveLastItem: `this.myBindingSource.MoveLast();`
    //AddNewItem: `this.myBindingSource.AddNew();`
    //DeleteItem: `this.myBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and detailed examples. One question I have is that if I set the save button up like the top example, will that handle the current form's record only or every record within the table? Because I see the issue in that you'd  need to run the validation methods every time you use a control from the navigation bar the active record is changes therefore allowing the option to press the save button while invalid records are present in the table.

Comment: Another important thing that you should pay attention to is, this type of validation is client side validation and for example if you have some services that you pass forms data to those services, you should perform buisiness validations on server side and you should not rely on the client side validation only.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this sounds to be exactly what I'm looking for! In response to your final point, I'm only passing the entered data to an SQL table and recovering it through the same application, I assume the extra validation stages would be unnecessary since all data in the table already will match what is to be expected?

Comment: You are welcome, If you don't have a service layer (or business layer) you don't need double check.

Comment: I have tried the solution you have provided above and the errorprovider fires correctly IF the user enters a second textbox. The user is still able to click the toolstrip buttons which therefore means they can still bypass the validation. I have set the `bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click` event to the code you provided with `if (!this.ValidateChildren()) return;`  and I'm still having no luck! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Once you have typed in a name which is too long, the user is still able to use the toolstrip buttons such as `Previous record` `First record` and `Add new record` without any errors appearing. The program then crashes as the text that is being submitted is too long for what the SQL table was expecting EDIT: `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?`

Comment: Yes I think that is the case. If the user selects a second textbox focus is maintained and no textboxes can be entered. I believe it is only the toolstrip buttons which are causing an issue.

Comment: If you have correct validation rules and write your validating events correctly, and set `EnablePreventFocusChange` for your form, I believe you can not navigate or add new item with breaking validation rules. The only case that I can imagine for breaking rules is these scenario. **1-** You click add new button. **2-** You add a valid vaue in one of text boxes while the others are invalid( because of being empty) **3-** Click Previous button and then you have entered an invalid data in the record.

Comment: Yes. I believe it is cases 1 and 3 above.

Comment: I think the edit is the ultimate solution. Check the edit and read it carefully :)

Comment: Yes. This is the perfect solution working exactly as I require. Thanks for being persistent and helping me out in detail. Great response!